# How to format the date in Typescript to the required one

Tags: angular, datetime, typescript

I have a datestring like 2016-09-19T18:10:31+0100. I'm doing

```
let dateString:string = 2016-09-19T18:10:31+0100;
let newDateString:Date = new Date(dateString);
```

And I'm getting the output as Tue Sep 19 2016 18:10:31 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time). But I want the date in the format of 19.9.2016 18:10

How do I format it to have have a desired format?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **DatePipe** in html template like this-

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template:`<h1>My First Angular 2 App</h1>
  <p>{{newDateString | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm'}} - format: dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm</p>`
})
export class AppComponent { 

  dateString: string = "2016-09-19T18:10:31+0100";
  newDateString:Date = new Date(this.dateString);
}
```

DatePipe documentation: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/DatePipe-pipe.html#!#sts=Pipe

---

**UPDATE:**

If you just want to format datetime in typescript (without angular2) then you can try like this-

```
  options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric', hour:'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: false };
  displayDate = new Date().toLocaleDateString(undefined, this.options);
```

In 2nd line, instead of `undefined` you can pass `locales` values like this- "en-US", "en-GB" etc.

Comment: I cannot use format the date in HTML since I'm using third party module (Ag Grid) so I need to supply formatted date to HTML